# How to write a function that handles a Union type in Dhall

Tags: functional-programming, dhall

I'm trying to wrap my head around how programming works in Dhall. Consider the following union type:

```
let Object = < NoId | WithId : Text >
```

I want to write a function `extractId` that returns an `Optional Text` containing the Id (or `None`), but I can't find a way to do the destructuring in Dhall.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to use the `merge` function. It expects a set with one handler function for each constructor of the union type. So to turn the above example union into an `Optional Text`, we can do:

```
let someObject = Object.NoId

let handlers = { NoId = None Text, WithId = λ(t : Text) → Some t }

in  merge handlers someObject
```